# Работа с записями в Паскале

Tags: pascal

Как заменить повторяющееся действия в конце при реализации второго условия(три раза пишу почти одинаковый цикл)?

Дан файл библ, содержащий сведения о книгах. Сведения о каждой из книг – это фамилия автора, название и год издания.
     а) Найти названия книг данного автора, изданных с 1960 года.
     б) Определить, имеется ли книга с названием “Информатика”. Если да, то сообщить фамилию автора и год издания. Если таких книг несколько, то сообщить имеющееся сведения обо всех этих книгах.

`uses crt;
Type Book=record     {Запись описывающая книгу}
                autor:string[20]; {Автор}
        title:string[20]; {Заголовок}
        year:word;       {Год}
    end;
cat=file of book; {тип - каталог книг}
Var
 f:cat;
 a:book;
 bibl,au:string;
 y:word;
 i,j:integer;
Begin
 assign(f,bibl+'.dat');  {связываем файл с именем на носителе}
 rewrite(f);      {открываем файл для записи (создаём новый)}
 writeln('Нажмите esc для выхода');
 repeat{ввод данных}
   writeln('Автор:');
   readln(a.autor);
   writeln('Название:');
   readln(a.title);
   writeln('Год издания:');
   readln(a.year);
   write(f,a);   {пишем структуру в файл}
  until readkey=#27; {пока не нажата клавиша esc (её код = 27)}
  close(f);       {закрываем файл, чтобы сохранить изменения }
  reset (f); {открываем файл для чтения}
writeln('Введите автора для поиска:');
readln(au);
i:=0;
while not eof(f) do {читаем пока не конец файла}
begin
read(f,a);{считываем очередную запись}
if (a.autor=au) and (a.year>=1960) then {если она удовлетворяет условию}
begin writeln(a.title);  {выводим название книги}   i:=i+1;   end;
end;
if i=0 then writeln('Книги не найдены');
close(f);
reset(f);
Writeln('Поиск книги с названием "Информатика":');
j:=0;
while not eof(f) do {читаем пока не конец файла}
begin
read(f,a);{считываем очередную запись}
if (a.title='Информатика') then j:=j+1;
end;
close(f);
reset(f);
if j=1 then while not eof(f) do {читаем пока не конец файла}
begin
read(f,a);{считываем очередную запись}
if (a.title='Информатика') then writeln(a.autor,' ',a.year); end;
if j>1 then while not eof(f) do {читаем пока не конец файла}
begin
read(f,a);{считываем очередную запись}
if (a.title='Информатика') then writeln(a.autor,' ',a.title,' ',a.year); end;
if j=0 then writeln('Книг с таким названием нет в базе данных');
close(f);
readkey;
end.`

Comment: Рекомендую использовать отступы для логического выделения блоков кода и, если необходимо, пустые строки для разделения участков кода, выполняющих разные действия. Это сэкономит Вам кучу времени и нервов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код я поправил: у меня эта прога прекрасно работает. Удалил из Вашего кода всё, что считаю лишним.

```
    uses crt;
Type Book=record     {Запись описывающая книгу}
                autor:string[20]; {Автор}
        title:string[20]; {Заголовок}
        year:word;       {Год}
    end;
cat=file of book; {тип - каталог книг}
Var
 f:cat;
 a:book;
 bibl,au:string;
 y:word;
 {i,j:integer;}
 Finded: Boolean;
Begin
 assign(f, 'bibl.dat');  {связываем файл с именем на носителе}
 rewrite(f);      {открываем файл для записи (создаём новый)}
 writeln('Нажмите esc для выхода');
 repeat{ввод данных}
   write('Автор:');
   readln(a.autor);
   write('Название:');
   readln(a.title);
   write('Год издания:');
   readln(a.year);
   write(f,a);   {пишем структуру в файл}
  until readkey=#27; {пока не нажата клавиша esc (её код = 27)}
  close(f);       {закрываем файл, чтобы сохранить изменения }
  reset (f); {открываем файл для чтения}
write('Введите автора для поиска:');
readln(au);
{i:=0; я бы использовал переменную типа Boolean - меньше места занимает и уместнее}
Finded:=False;
while not eof(f) do {читаем пока не конец файла}
begin
read(f,a);{считываем очередную запись}
if (a.autor=au) and (a.year>=1960) then {если она удовлетворяет условию}
begin 
  writeln(a.title);  {выводим название книги}
  Finded:=True;
  {i:=i+1;}   
end;
end;
if Not(Finded) then writeln('Книги не найдены');
close(f);

Writeln('Поиск книги с названием "Информатика":');

reset(f);

while not eof(f) do {читаем пока не конец файла}
begin
  read(f,a);{считываем очередную запись}
  if (a.title='Информатика') then 
    writeln(a.autor,' ',a.title,' ',a.year);
end;
close(f);
readkey;
end.
```

Позвольте дать пару советов: если нужно создать флаг для поиска, то лучше пользоваться логическими переменными (тип Boolean, значения True False) - с ними и в условиях легче работать, и весят они меньше; как Вам уже сказал [@Андрей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/202/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9) форматируйте код (Ваш код понятен, благодаря комментариям, но трудно воспринимается).

P.S. Компилировал в PascalABC.NET.